# Prove some divisibility with deductive way

Tags: education

I have some proves But I want to prove them with **deductive** not **inductive**.
Here are my proves:

1) $2^{3n} - 1 $ is divisible by 7.

2) $2^n + (-1)^{n+1}$ is divisible by 3.

3) $n^2 + 2$ is not divisible by 4.

4) $11^n - 4^n$ is divisible by 7.

Is it possible to help me? (some of them is good too).
Thanks.

Comment: Too many questions together... Make them separate.

Comment: Look up the topics "congruence " and "modular arithmetic" in the subject "number theory". It's easy to learn the basics of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $2^{3n} - 1 = 8^n-1 = (8-1)a = 7a$ where a is the other factor. 
   Hence, $2^{3n} - 1 $ is divisible by 7.
2. $2^n + (-1)^{n+1} = 2^n - (-1)^n = [2-(-1)]b = 3b$ where b is the other factor. 
   Hence,$2^n + (-1)^{n+1}$ is divisible by 3.
3. $n^2 + 2 = 4k + 2 = 2(2k+1) = 2 \times \text{odd number}$, not divisible by $4$ ,when $n$ is even
   $n^2 + 2 = 8k+1+2 = 8k+3$, not divisible by $4$, when $n$ is odd 
   Hence, $n^2 + 2$ is not divisible by 4.
4. $11^n - 4^n = (11-4)c = 7c$ where c is the other factor. 
   Hence, $11^n - 4^n$ is divisible by 7.

Comment: thanks. I can't vote for you because my reputation. just question about third one. when our number is even we use ${(2k)}^2 = 4k^2$ or we say $n^2$ is even so we use $n^2 = 2k$. How can we use $4k$ because how can we make number 2 with this format. (maybe k is from R not Z) Is it true?

Comment: Yes of course its true. $n^2=(2k)^2=4k^2=4m$ for $m=k^2$. And if you like my answer, you can accept it any time :)

Comment: I accept that. thanks again. :)

Comment: You're welcome.